# Перевести js в php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Всем привет!
У меня есть массив с объектами (data), также есть функция, которая выводить разметку и элементами из объектов внутри массива. Мне нужно перевести этот js в php, чтобы использовать его внутри  как это сделать правильно?

Вот сам js

```
const data = [
    {
     title: "this title1",
    description: "this description1",
        number: "this number1",
  },
    {
     title: "this title2",
    description: "this description2",
        number: "this number2",
  },
]
    
    function outputGoods(goods) {
     document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = goods
    .map(
      (n) => `
       <div class="wrapper">
          <div> ${n.title}</div>
            <div> ${n.description}</div>
            <div> ${n.number}</div>
      </div>
         
        outputGoods(data)
```

А вот, что я пробовал:

```
$data = [
    {
     'title'=>'this title1',
    'description'=> 'this description1',
        'number'=> '12',
  },
    {
      'title'=>'this title2',
    'description'=> 'this description2',
        'number'=> '24',
  },
]
    
    function outputGoods($goods) {
     echo document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = $goods
    .map(
      (n) => `
       <div class="wrapper">
          <div> ${n.title}</div>
            <div> ${n.description}</div>
            <div> ${n.number}</div>
      </div>
         
        outputGoods($data)
?>
```

но это не работает:(

Comment: Очень интересно=)) Вы получаете дом объект вне построенного дерева? Ещё и конкатенация строк.... Для чего вам это? Какой результат вы хотите получить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
<?php
$data = [ 
    [
        'title'=>'this title1',
        'description'=> 'this description1',
        'number'=> '12'
    ],
    [
        'title'=>'this title2',
        'description'=> 'this description2',
        'number'=> '24'
    ]
];

function outputGoods($goods)
{
echo "<div class=\"wrapper\">"
     . array_reduce($goods,
         function ($string, $item)
         {
             $string .= "<div>"
             . $item['title']
             . "</div> <div>" 
             . $item['description']
             . "</div> <div>" 
             . $item['number']
             . "</div>";
             return $string;
         }, "")
     . "</div>";
}

outputGoods($data);
?>
```